Albedo of water vs temperature
This question arose out of pure curiosity.
Is there a relation between the temperature of water and its albedo? Would the albedo increase if I increased temperature? Say I measure albedo by directing a beam of light of fixed intensity at 45 degrees into the water and then measuring the intensity of the reflected beam.
Does the Stefan Boltzmann Law apply here? If it does then is there a polynomial relation between albedo and temperature.
Edit: According to the comments SB does not apply, so is there a law that does apply?
Edit2: And now there is a conflicting answer. If SB does apply then what is the justification for it?
Edit3: Do the fressnal equations apply here?

The Stefan-Boltzann law does not apply because that law is about thermal emission of a (near) black body. Your question is about reflection. Your question is still valid though.

That's fresnel's equation

The relationship between temperature and albedo is indirect.
The density of water, and the refractive index which is roughly proportional to density, vary (slightly) with temperature.
For a beam of light hitting the air-water interface at an angle, the reflected light is at the same angle, and the transmitted light is at an angle given by Snell's law.  The reflected and transmitted power depends on the angles ($\theta_i$) and refractive indexes ($n_1$ and $n_2$) according to the Fresnel equations

Here $n_2$ would have a slight temperature dependence as described above.
I think "albedo" would be the reflected light intensity when the light is normal to the interface, so just plug in 90 degrees for the angle, $n_1$ = 1 (the refractive index of free space) and $n_2$ = the refractive index of water at the temperature of interest.
The intensities $R_s$ and $R_p$ are different for s- and p- polarized light, but only when the angle is not 90 degrees (because the $cos (\theta_i)$ term becomes zero)

However I don't understand how the asker links albedo with Fresnel equation. As they are quite independent.

@Ritzthephysibeast How so? Albedo=fraction of reflected light=exactly Rs and Rp, unless I’m missing something

I wanted to state that it was not true for sunlight. As albedo, is not just reflection but also transmission.

$$T=\sqrt [4]{{\frac{\alpha P_{incident}}{\varepsilon \sigma A}} + T_s^4}$$
This equation combines the two powers, P and
T. P is radiated power, and T is scattered power. Alpha is the absorption coefficient, and varepsilon is the emissivity. Sigma is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant. A is the surface area of the object.
Edit: Does the Stefan-Boltzmann Law apply to Non-Blackbody Objects?

The Stefan-Boltzmann Law applies to all real objects but as real objects do not absorb the complete radation (emissivity  <1), so radiation emitted by non-blackbody objects may not be proportional to the fourth power of their temperature.

From
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stefan-boltzmann-law/
The Fresnel equations (or Fresnel coefficients) describe the reflection and transmission of light (or electromagnetic radiation in general) when incident on an interface between different optical media., So, they are valid, if your radiation is electromagnetic (which is the only option here) .
I hope it answers you.

The comments say that SB law does not apply, so you can’t use it. Or if it does apply then you need to justify it.

@VivaanDaga Please see the edits

@VivaanDaga did you get your answer?

No, you haven’t said why SB applies.

@VivaanDaga that's what I explained in block quote. You might have missed reading that.
